# Populating a wide table with SSRS text parameter with a delimiter

Tags: text, reporting-services, parameters, multiple-columns, delimiter

I am trying to populate a table variable in SSRS and call a SP subsequently to process the data in it:

```
DECLARE @Tbl1 TABLE
(
    D01 float,
    D02 float,
    D03 float,
    D04 float,
    D05 float,
    ...
    D96 float
)
```

To populate it I use a text parameter @LS. The input is comma delimited string with 96 elements:

```
0.635316969,0.756943899,0.890520142,1.028008362,1.166350106,1.30511861,1.444527254,1.580948571,1.578743639,1.575542931,1.573195746,1.571346448,1.571275321,1.56992391,1.568003484,1.567221089,1.556836567,1.543820351,1.53037, ...., ,0.514543561
```

In a dataset I tried to populate the table first (after table variable declaration):

```
insert into @Tbl1
VALUES (@LS)
```

But got this error at run-time: "Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition."

I tried `JOIN(SPLIT())` with comma without luck. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.   You'll likely get better answers if you format your question for ease of readability, as I've done above.   Cheers...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the the `@LS` parameter is a single-value text parameter so you can't use it like that - you'd need to use a multi-value parameter.

So let's try something different. You don't need to create a temporary table because you could build your column values to give a dataset that you want using Sql like this:

```
SELECT 0.635316969 AS D01, 0.756943899 AS D02, ... , 0.514543561 AS D96
```

Fortunately almost everything in SSRS is an expression, so we just need to build this Sql statement dynamically from the `@LS` parameter using an expression. Go to the `Report` menu then `Report Properties...` and click the `Code` tab. Enter the following code:

```
Function MakeSql(LS As String) As String
  Dim Sql As String
  Dim Values() As String 
  Dim i As Integer

  Sql = "SELECT " 
  Values = Split(LS, ",")

  For i = 0 To Values.Length - 1
    Sql = Sql + Values(i) + " AS D" + Right("0" + CStr(i+1), 2) + ", "
  Next i

  Sql = Left(Sql, Len(Sql) - 2) ' Remove trailing comma

  Return Sql
End Function
```

So what we are doing is splitting the string into an array of values which we loop through to create a Sql statement that aliases these values to the field names we want.

Right-click your dataset, choose `Dataset Properties` and press the `fx` button beside the query textbox. This allows us to enter a text expression for our Sql statement rather than an actual Sql statement. Here we need to call the custom code function we created above which will insert our custom built Sql expression:

```
=Code.MakeSql(Parameters!LS.Value)
```

Make sure your dataset has the fields `D01` to `D96` (you'll have to set these up manually because SSRS can't analyse the Sql expression to determine the field values) and you're done!

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! It looks like I will need Visual Studio to include code, as I am only using Report Builder alone now, correct? If so maybe the I will need similar code in a SQL UDF?

Comment: [This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms159238.aspx) suggests that you can use embedded code in Report Builder but I use Visual Studio so I don't know how it is done there. You could also create a similar SQL UDF that executes a query based on the dynamically built SQL statement and passes back the dataset. If this is something that will be used across multiple reports then that is the preferred method.